# How to parse JSON with no key?

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse a big load of JSON, and it turns out its a big array consisting of 20 dictionaries. And Im just wondering how i'd parse it into multiple NSDictionaries?
I'm used to just doing this with JSON:

```
NSDictionary *tDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

But the JSON I'm trying to parse looks like this:

```
[{
"key": "value"
"key": {
    "key": "value"
    "key": "value"
    }
},
{
"key": "value"
"key": {
    "key": "value"
    "key": "value"
    }
},
{
"key": "value"
"key": {
    "key": "value"
    "key": "value"
    }
}]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is change it from:

```
NSDictionary *tDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

to:

```
NSArray *tArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Then what you have is an `NSArray` full of `NSDictionary`'s.

Comment: I've done this bit :) But how would i extract that into multiple dictionaries?

NSDictionary *dictionary1 = tArray[0];
?

Comment: Yes it would be NSDictionary *dict0 = [tArray objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score -1):

What do you expect? Your JSON is an array of dictionaries so that is what `NSJSONSerialization` returns to you. Anything else would be wrong.

Besides, how should this method return "multiple NSDictionaries" to you? The only way this can be done is by sticking them into some kind of container like an `NSArray` or `NSSet`. And since the JSON specification says that your JSON is an array `NSArray` (or maybe `NSMutableArray` which you can get by specifying the right flags) is the only logical choice.

Comment: I wasnt saying this is how i would try to parse it in this situation, I was pointing out that ive only every done it that way and maybe it was similar.